# List copy mechanism in python

Tags: python, list, mutation

I know that copying list with the following code will perform a shallow copy. i.e New list is created.

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> L_copy = L[:]
>>> L_copy

>>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> L_copy is L
```

> > > False

How is the following code executed:

> > > L[:] = some_list

I saw it in one example.

This is my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking. Do you understand list slicing?

Comment: The code basically erases the contents of L and puts the new list's contents in it.

Answer (score 0):

`L[:]` created an object that is equal to but it's not the same object.

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> _L = L[:]
>>> print L,_L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> L == _L
True
>>> L is _L
False
>>>
```

All, that `is` tells you is that `L` and `_L` are not the same object.

```
>>> L[:] == L[:]
True
>>> L[:] is L[:]
False
>>>
```